# Ocasioanlly long wait time for ajax post

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, database

I am not sure why, but sometimes my post to the server to get data back takes a really long time (21s), but at others times it is really fast (32ms). I've checked my store procedure to get see how long it take to execute the query and it is fast. I suspect that it might be because I am maxing out the allowed connection for the browser. I am not sure, but the long wait time usually happens after a couple of refreshes, but once in awhile when I navigate back to that page the post will wait a really long time. Other than that it works fine. Is there a way for me to find out if it is because I am maxing out the allowed connection, or something else? I am not sure what to post, so here is the code for the ajax post

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/url/postit",
    cache: false,
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: Content,
    success: function (results) {
        console.log(results);        
        //Do nothing
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus + ", " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the application pool that is associated with your service is timing out due to being idle.  Then each time you hit the service the application has to be loaded again.

I would check the idle timeout of the app pool.  Find the app pool in IIS, right click and go to **Advanced Settings**.  Then look under **Process Model** for the **Idle Time-out (minutes)** setting.

The text from that setting:

> Amount of time (in minutes) a worker process will remain idle before it shuts down. A worker process is idle if it is not processing requests and no new requests are received.

Comment: Interesting, idle-time out is set to 20 minutes already, but I have not had a chance to test anything out yet, I got some code that broke my build so I am working to get my stuff working again

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer but it seem that the new code fixed it. Apearently it was not ym code but someones that was taking a really long time and was making my post wait. After the build error got fixed the long waiting time wnet a way.

Comment: a good read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27740692/request-stalled-for-a-long-time-occasionally-in-chrome