# Connect to a custom local site with a custom name

Tags: localhost

I'm trying to connect to a local server running on my Mac from a mobile phone on the same network. My local server name is testsite.dev and running locally on port 8888. Is there any way/service that would let me connect to testsite.dev:8888 from my phone?

Update: So I tried to access it from another computer and it chrome network tab says its stalling the request when it gets redirected to testsite.dev and it's possible that this may be why https://stackoverflow.com/a/29732252/3640511

Comment: If you're trying to test on an iphone I know that the xcode simulator lets you open up safari, so you would be able to go to testsite.dev:8888 as you would on your browser

Comment: Good suggestion, but for some reason it times out and it says server stopped responding.

Answer (score 0):

If your computer and mobile are on same network (using wifi? Cellular networks might act differently), you can access your 'local' server using ip of your computer.

Try executing `ifconfig | grep inet | grep -v inet6 | grep -v '127.0.0.1'` on your mac to get your mac's IP. Once you have your mac's ip address, you can access your server from your mobile as `<ip-address>:8888`.

Comment: I tried this and it redirects me to testsite.dev:8888 but then it times out