# Google Chrome: HTTP GET on localhost, inconsistent load times

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In my Angular2 project I have a component that loads JSON data via HTTP, and displays it on the page as a grid.  The grid has pagination and the component performs a new HTTP GET each time a new grid page is requested.   The dev site is hosted on localhost, as is the webservice, but they use different port numbers.

The component works without any errors. However, I have noticed that in Google Chrome the HTTP GET response time seems to fluctuate up & down for no obvious reason.  This only happens in Chrome.  In Firefox there are no issues.

When I deploy the site to live there are no issues in Chrome OR Firefox so this problem is specific to Chrome + my dev environment/possibly the localhost URLs.

Here is a screenshot of my Google Chrome network tab on the development site: 
[image]

If you look at the **Time** column you can see the time fluctuates between approx 80ms and 380ms for each consecutive request.  380ms is almost 5x longer, so as you'd expect the grid component refresh is noticeably delayed every time there's a slower response.  Again, this only happens in Chrome.

Digging deeper, here is a screenshot of the timings for a slow HTTP GET: 
[image]

You can see from the above example that the webservice responds in approx 75ms, but Chrome reports that the whole operation took 377ms?!  Looking at the timings I have no idea where 377ms came from, because the other figures clearly do not add up to 377ms.  However, looking at the visual timing bars, there's a massive gap between `DNS Lookup` and `Initial Connection`!

And, here's a screenshot for a faster HTTP GET:
[image]

As you can see from the above timings, there is no `DNS lookup` or `Initial Connection` sections, like there is in the previous screenshot which is a bit odd?

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might go about pin-pointing and resolving the issue here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: My Suggestion is that, you should try a couple of things.
1) Try Firefox if the same problem happens
2) Use a JSON get client, such as postman or even curl, and see if it is the api server. 
As ur title mention chrome, I would assume you have tried on chrome and the info is not enough to determine it it is a browser issue or the code.

Comment: I have already tried Firefox, as mentioned in my question.  Firefox has no issues at all.  I have benchmarked the .NET Core webservice and it returns a response in around 80ms each time.  I think there is quite a bit of evidence pointing towards a browser issue or a local dev environment setup issue that Chrome does not like

Comment: First thing first, I notice that ur **Slow** HTTP Get screenshot has additional DNS lookup under connection setup.

Where ur **Fast** Http get doesn't. I've also checked mine, is w/o dns lookups.

Usually, chrome has long stalls, but that doesn't show in your **Slow** screenshot. Assume it is a stall, you TTFB time is about the same as your **Fast**.

There is a similar problem as your [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27740692/request-stalled-for-a-long-time-occasionally-in-chrome).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  I managed to fix it by using a different name to 'localhost'.  I added `127.0.0.1 testsite` to my hosts files, and then changed my dev server url to `http//testsite:3000`.  I don't really know why this works, but it seems Chrome was getting confused about the dns for `localhost`.  Very strange :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick update: I managed to fix the issue in the end by using a different host name for my dev site.

I added `127.0.0.1 testsite` into my hosts file, then changed my dev server URL to `http://testsite:3000`.  I was previously using `http://localhost:3000`.  After that the HTTP GETs all dropped to a consistent 80ms-ish and there were no more DNS Lookup issues in the Network tab of the Developer Tools.

Not exactly sure of the source, but using `localhost` as the host was causing an issue somewhere.

Comment: Weird yet interesting issue. If you're using linux, a localhost is pretty much the same as ```testsite``` define in host file. Nevertheless, glad u solve find the problem. Perhaps another thing u can try is that, u could probably clear chrome's dns cache, chrome://net-internals/#dns. To see if it helps.

Comment: If you cannot edit the hosts file (managed machine etc.) running http://127.0.0.1:3000 solves it as well! Had the same problem with chrome and edge today